# Accessing data from one table which not belong to the other two table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

//sample database

At first Scholar has 1,2,3,4,5,6 ids

```
Scholar      
Id      
1   
2
3
4
5
6
```

Now 1 and 2 were taken under table Member

```
Member 
Id
1 - taken
2 - taken
```

Next 3 and 4 were taken under table AddRequest

```
AddRequest
Id
3 - taken
4 - taken
```

now the Scholar table should only has the ids 5 and 6 which i want to display.

how can i resolve this problem using my code below

```
public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id)
{
    $members = Member::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->get();
    $members = $members->toArray();
    $scholar_ids = array_pluck($members, 'scholar_id');
    $scholar_exits = Scholar::whereNotIn('scholar_id', $scholar_ids)->get();

    $requests = AddRequest::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->get();
    $requests = $requests->toArray();
    $scholar_ids = array_pluck($requests, 'scholar_id');
    $add_exits = Scholar::whereNotIn('scholar_id', $scholar_ids)->get();   

    if ($scholar_exits == true && $add_exits == true) {

    $scholars = (new Scholar)->newQuery()->select('*');

    $scholars = $scholars->get();
    dd($scholars);
}else{
}
}
```

result of dd

```
Collection {#302 ▼
  #items: array:7 [▼
    0 => Scholar {#305 ▶}
    1 => Scholar {#306 ▶}
    2 => Scholar {#307 ▶}
    3 => Scholar {#308 ▶}
    4 => Scholar {#309 ▶}
    5 => Scholar {#310 ▶}
    6 => Scholar {#311 ▶}
  ]
}
```

[This for Member and AddRequest Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9p1A.png)

[This for Scholar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5q9x.png)

Comment: Can you create full SQL against this? If so, just left join from Scholar to Member and AddRequest and filter for Member.Id IS NULL and AddRequest.Id IS NULL

Comment: Can i have other way other than join?Im using laravel eloquent.I just want to view the Scholar list  that ids are not in MEMBER and AddRequest table Step  one: I have a button that will add scholar  to Member but it will pass first to Addrequest table becuase it is still considered as pending.When it  is being accepted..this ids/id will be move to Member table so it cant be seen anymore from Addrequest table because i made a fucntion that can delete it automatically and move to/or insert to Member table.So What belongs to Member or Addrequest table is no longer available in Scholar table.\

Answer (score 0):

After all checking regarding the **members** and the **addRequests** you are trying to select everything from the **Scholar** table that is the reason why you are getting all six records.

I would add two fields like`is-member` and `has-request` to the `scholar` table and update the boolean values to true based on events like - `is-member becomes true when the Scholar transitions to become a member` and `has-request becomes true when the Scholar add a request` or something like that. So then it becomes very easy to get scholars who are neither members nor do they have any requests.

However in your case, I think you should try as below:

```
public function ListOrgaScholar($ship_id)
{
    $scholar_ids = [];
    $members = Member::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->get();
    //$members = $members->toArray();
    //$scholar_ids = array_pluck($members, 'scholar_id');
    //$scholar_exits = Scholar::whereNotIn('scholar_id', $scholar_ids)->get();
    foreach($members as $member){
        $scholar_ids[] = $member->scholar_id;
    }

    $requests = AddRequest::where('ship_id','=',$ship_id)->get();
    //$requests = $requests->toArray();
    //$request_scholar_ids = array_pluck($requests, 'scholar_id');
    //$add_exits = Scholar::whereNotIn('scholar_id', $scholar_ids)->get();
    foreach($requests as $request){
        $scholar_ids[] = $request->scholar_id;
    }   

    $scholars = Scholar::whereNoIn('scholar_id', $scholar_ids)->get();
    dd($scholars);
}
```